# Visual Studio 2019 cannot view static variables defined at App level in Watch window

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, static-variables, watch-window

I have a Xamarin Forms app in Visual Studio 2019 and I have several static class variables defined in the App.xaml.cs file.  I use these variables through out my application.  However, when I am on a page of my app and add a property of the Static Class variable to the watch window, I receive the error message:

Watch Window Entry:

```
App.gvm_WaitingList
```

Error:

```
error CS0103: The name 'App' does not exist in the current context.
```

This makes it very hard to debug when I cannot see the values of properties in these static classes.  Here is how the variable is defined in the App.xaml.cs

```
public static VM_WaitingList gvm_WaitingList;
```

and then I initialize it in the App constructor as follows:

```
gvm_WaitingList = new VM_WaitingList();
```

In searching for a solution I did find talk about the immediate window and adding global:: before the item I want to watch.  However, when I do that I get the following error:

Watch Window Entry:

```
global::App.gvm_WaitingList
```

Error:

```
error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to see these variables.  If I prefix the variable in the watch window with the namespace, it will resolve the variable in the watch window.  Here is the solution that fixed my problem:

(NOTE my namespace is UniversalCheckInHost) 
Watch Window Entry:

```
UniversalCheckInHost.App.gvm_WaitingList
```

I hope this helps someone else.